# onReceive will always receive the last appWidgetId, even different instance widget is being pressed

Tags: android

I have the following code. I tried to place 2 instance of widgets in my home screen.

Here is the log being printed, after 2 instance of widgets had been placed.

```
onUpdate START
onUpdate 170
onUpdate START
onUpdate 171
```

When I click on 1st widget followed by 2nd widget, I expect 170 and 171 will be printed respectively. However, this is what I get.

```
onReceive 171  <-- I'm expecting 170 to be printed.
onReceive 171
```

Is there anything wrong with my code? Or, I'm having wrong expectation?

```
public class MyAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {    
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        Log.i("CHEOK", "onUpdate START");

        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            Log.i("CHEOK", "onUpdate " + appWidgetId);

            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout_inverse_holo_light);

            // Register an onClickListener
            Intent refreshIntent = new Intent(context, JStockAppWidgetProvider.class);
            refreshIntent.setAction(REFRESH_ACTION);
            refreshIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
            PendingIntent refreshPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, refreshIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);            
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.refresh_button, refreshPendingIntent);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        AppWidgetManager mgr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        if (intent.getAction().equals(REFRESH_ACTION)) {
            int appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);

            Log.i("CHEOK", "onReceive " + appWidgetId);

            // How can I access my remoteView?
            // During onUpdate, is saving all the remoteViews in local member
            // Map<appWidgetId, remoteView> a good idea?
        }
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }

    private static final String REFRESH_ACTION = "org.yccheok.jstock.gui.widget.MyAppWidgetProvider.REFRESH_ACTION";  
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because both your PendingIntent are treated the same, hence creating the second one will replace the first one, refer to:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#filterEquals%28android.content.Intent%29

> Determine if two intents are the same for the purposes of intent
>   resolution (filtering). That is, if their action, data, type, class,
>   and categories are the same. This does not compare any extra data
>   included in the intents.

So yours is only different by the Extra, which doesn't work. Try to set something with setData.

```
refreshIntent.setData(Uri.parse(refreshIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
```

Comment: What about `PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, appWidgetId, intent, 0);`. Should work as well as the requestCode is different for each widget? Or is it a bad practice?

Comment: @Phuah Yee Keat  I have a similar use case for an alarm and a PendingIntent that fires and Intent.  It sends a message to a BroadcastReceiver that then sends a message to a Service to fire a Notification.  I used your setData example but the Notification is not firing.  Do I need to add a <data /> element in the BroadcastReceiver's intent-filter in the Manifest?  to account for the Uri scheme?